# EditText.settext from another class

Tags: android

Hi I am totally new to android, so this is a very basic question.

I want to change the text in a Edittext from another class but the  program crashes every time.

My question is, how do i call newTxt() from another class (that extends homesc1 )?

This is my code.

```
public class homesc1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public EditText clickEditText;
    int count =0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        clickEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextClick);
        newTxt("Works fine. call from same class");
    }

    public void newTxt(String txt) {
        clickEditText.setText(txt);
    }
}

public class SubC extends homesc1 {
 public void retur(){
  //clickEditText.setText("RETUR");
  newTxt("this crashes the program, no compile error");
 }
} 

// called is other class with:

SubC SC = new SubC();
SC.retur();
```

[EDIT] the Log Cat:

```
02-16 18:40:44.705: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(447): ERROR: thread attach failed
02-16 18:40:46.795: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(455): ERROR: thread attach failed
02-16 18:40:47.705: WARN/dalvikvm(462): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
02-16 18:40:47.727: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.huskkage.android.but2ud/com.huskkage.android.but2ud.homesc1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1612)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at com.huskkage.android.but2ud.homesc1.newTxt(homesc1.java:67)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at com.huskkage.android.but2ud.SubC.retur(SubC.java:10)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at com.huskkage.android.but2ud.homesc1.onCreate(homesc1.java:56)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
02-16 18:40:47.755: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(462):     ... 11 more
02-16 18:40:47.805: ERROR/dalvikvm(462): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
02-16 18:40:56.735: WARN/ActivityManager(63): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
02-16 18:40:57.247: WARN/ActivityManager(63): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43d5ed00 com.huskkage.android.but2ud/.homesc1}
```

Comment: Show you you are attempting to change the text from another class. And paste the logcat trace after the app crashes.

Comment: Java code looks OK to me. Check your main.xml actually has an <EditText> with an attribute exactly like this: android:id="@+id/editTextClick"

Comment: Are you creating the instance of the subclass yourself using new?

Comment: @ Cristian. i have try ed many things, but something like this.

Comment: Why do you make a subclass of your Activity class? Would be nice to see the subclass code.

Comment: public class SubC extends homesc1 {

 public void retur(){
  //clickEditText.setText("RETUR");
  newTxt("this crashes the program, no compile error");
 }
 
}    //  called is other class with: SubC SC = new SubC();
       SC.retur();

Comment: maybe i am asking the wrong way. i guess what i should be asking is what is standard/best practice, way to change the text i an EditText from another class.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't access UI elements of Activity from another non-inner class.

Comment: @Markiz Lonkly -- Of course you can, as long as you've put the widget in a public variable somewhere.

Comment: Can you post the output of the log cat?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your `onCreate` in your instance of `SubC`.

You do not appear to be calling `super.onCreate`, which means `clickEditText` will never be initialised and that is likely the source of the problem since it will be uninitialised when you call `newTxt()` from your subclass, likely causing a `NullPointerException`.

Just add

```
super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
```

to the beginning of your subclass onCreate, and that should fix the problem.

Comment: Except they're creating an activity with new, so it will not work as desired.

Comment: that gives me a syntax Error !?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new class that extends your activity also ends up creating another activity ( that the system does not control at all ) that likely does not follow the proper init process, so nothing gets set up properly on your subclass.

Even if everything got set up properly worked, the subclass is not referring to your current activity instance, but its very own.

If you can guarantee the activity will be around for as long or longer as the other class will, you can pass the activity as part of the constructor to the second class, then call your method using that variable. ( Be aware that if you have extra references to your activity floating around, you *will* leak memory )

Comment: ok, i do not want i new activity. all i want is to settext in a editbox, based on info from another class. how is that done?

Comment: Read the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Global class to store my activities when they're created. This way I can influence their views from other classes.

`public static Activity gActivity = null;
public static Context gContext = null;`

`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate){
  Global.gActivity = (Activity)this;
  Global.gContext = (Context)this;
}`

Comment: You've got to be careful with this though -- you are holding a Activity someplace outside it's own self, so it will stick around even when it goes away, and that can cause errors or a memory leak.

Comment: Yes it does consume more memory but does not leak as GC will release the old activity if the same one is ever created.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to your newTxt(s) method:

```
if (clickEditText == null) 
      clickEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextClick);
clickEditText.setText(s);
```

Or if your newText() method doesn't do anything beyond what you've shown here I would do away with it and just call findViewById() and setText() from both activities without making a seperate method.

Comment: interesting. i get inside the if (clickEditText == null) (verified by changing a String for there ) but the program crashes again on clickEditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextClick);

Comment: You need to cast it as an EditText i'll update my answer to fix that

Answer (score 0):

You can't change TextView from Thread object, it doesn't have access to UI. It would take much time to explain, so You should find out it yourself.

Simpliest way is to use AsyncTask instead of Thread, and interact with UI using onPreExecute(), onPostExecute() & publishProgress() of AsyncTask.